# Issue installing scons in Dockerfile -- No match for argumet scons using yum

Tags: docker, centos, centos7, scons

I am trying to create a docker image from centos that uses scons.

The simple Dockerfile I am trying right now is:

```
FROM centos:latest
USER root
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum -y install scons
```

however, when I run docker build, I get the following error:

> No match for argument: scons Error: Unable to find a match The command
>   '/bin/sh -c yum -y install scons' returned a non-zero code: 1

From what I understand I should be able to yum install scons, is there another way I need to do this in a Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this something to do with the base image, but this [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/orion/dockerfile/) is base on centos7 and it seems working.

```
FROM centos:centos7.6.1810
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum -y install epel-release && \
    yum -y install scons
RUN  scons --version
```

Comment: It appears it may have to do with the centos version. When I run the above it works, however if I change the first line to be FROM centos:latest, I get the error again. Thanks for the help!